# Android Preference-tag accessibility

Tags: java, android, xml, accessibility

I have a settings screen in my app where I display some copyright text as a simple `Preference`.
However I want to override the default accessibility text. I can't set a `contentDescription` like I can on a normal `View`.

Any solutions?

Thanks

```
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <Preference
        android:key="@string/about_key_copyright_notice"
        android:title="@string/about_title_general" />
</PreferenceScreen>
```

Answer (score 0):

`android:summary` is what you're looking for

Comment: No this shows on the screen. I only want it to be spoken when Talkback is enabled.

Comment: I don't think it's possible. There's no such a thing: [in the docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/Preference.html)

Comment: You might want to create your own Preference class, extending Preference & implementing View as well